# Cancel "done" listener to jQuery AJAX Deferred?

Tags: ajax, jquery-deferred

If I have an AJAX request I initiated with a jQuery `$.ajax()` call, and at the time attached a `done()` listener to, is there a way to un-listen to it? I have a situation with a search-as-you-type field, where if a request gets made to the server that for whatever reason takes a long time to respond, but while waiting the user types a bit more and a second request fires and comes back quickly, when the first request eventually completes, the `done()` listener fires, rewriting the DOM with the the first request's data, not the second.

I've tried issuing an `abort()` call on the AJAX, or `reject()` on the Deferred right before the second request is made, but that shows the error state for the first call while the second call is in-flight.

I tried coming up with an ID system to hash out which request is the "current" one, so in the `done()` listener it first checks "am I still the most recent request?" before updating the DOM, but that seems clunky that the app needs to create an ID/Hash methodology for each API endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

On every done callback you could log a timestamp, and execute the callback only if the timestamp is the latest one yet. So:

```
var latest_ts = 0;
$.get('...').done(function() {
    var this_ts = (new Date).getTime();
    if (this_ts < latest_ts) return;
    latest_ts = this_ts;
    //callback code here...
});
```

So if request A is fired but request B is fired after it but returns first, the timestamp is updated and A's callback will be ignored, as its timestamp is out of date.

Comment: Indeed; I am already doing that, so requests aren't being fired on every keypress. The issue is a broad search (e.g. "e") returns a lot of results (and takes a while), while a more specific search (e.g. "ear") only returns a few results (and might return faster).

Comment: Hmmm, interesting idea, but not with that particular logic; you have `(new Date).getTime()` happening inside the `done()` handler, which only fires when the request resolves, and the order they resolve in is always the order they resolve in, so the timestamps would never be out of order. Marking the timestamp at the same level as the `$.get()` (marking the time when you start the request, not when it ends) is the same as setting an ID for the request; when it resolves, it needs to know which ID (timestamp) it was, to know if it changed.